# OpenCV's GrabCut produces unsatisfactory segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have the following image

[image]

I want to identify the main object in this image, which is the blue couch, and remove the background (preferably turn it into white). I use the code below, but it's not really doing the job as You can see in the second image. Is there better ways to do this rather than using opencv?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_bgr = cv2.imread('path/couch.PNG')
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

rectangle = (0,0,800,800)

mask = np.zeros(image_rgb.shape[:2], np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)

cv2.grabCut(image_rgb, mask, rectangle, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask_2 = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')

image_rgd_nobg = image_rgb * mask_2[:,:, np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(image_rgd_nobg)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]

Comment: One approach might be the inverse of the current approach.  Perhaps convert the image to HSV and extract the sofa as a mask, using the blue colour range.  With a bit of thresholding, this mask can be applied back to the original image to highlight the sofa. Granted, a bit more work will be involved, but that’s one viable approach.  And yes, cv2 is the right tool.

Comment: it's grabcut. it's a low level operation. if you expect AI results, use AI.

Comment: Your image is 511x366 or so and your rectangle is 800x800 (larger than your image), so you are not identifying the region of the object relative to your actual image size.

Comment: @S3DEV: Thanks. However, you tell me to use blue color range, but I have many images like this where the sofas (or other furniture) are of different colors. If it's a pillow and a couch on the photo, how does the program know which object to mask? I'm not sure it's that simple to fix if the images vary.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: What methods/algorithms do you suggest for this? Something like U2NET? Semantic segmentation?

Comment: @fmw42: Yes I actually tested several different sizes of that rectangle. But the problem is that I have lot's of images that I need to do this for and sometimes it's the pillow on the couch, sometimes the couch is grey, green etc.